# Testing a string with PHP

Tags: php

I am looking to run a test on a string to determine whether or not it meets certain condiditions. I would like to extract the last 4 characters of any given string and test them against a constant variable. Any Ideas on how to do this?

Ex:

morris@uakron.edu

I would like to know if the last four characters in the string are '.edu'

Thanks

Comment: are you dealing with only emails ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`substr`](http://php.net/substr) for single-byte and [`mb_substr`](http://php.net/mb_substr) for multi-byte strings:

```
$suffix = substr($str, -4);
```

The negative *start* parameter value specifies to start from the end of the string.

Comment: +1 because this user has 174k rep and so hes gotta be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, any of the following might work for you:

- [`strrpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) - find last occurrence within a string
- [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) - check the contents of a specific portion of a string
- [`preg_match()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) - complex pattern matching